# Cannot log in to admin after upgrade

Tags: upgrade, pyrocms

I need some help troubleshooting.

I've just upgraded my 1.3 site to 2.0 (with the intent of going on to 2.1). I get the actual page running, content is read from DB etc, but I cannot log in to the admin panel!

Just to make sure I didn't forget the password I did

```
<?php echo sha1('password' . 'salt'); ?>
```

Taking the salt from the DB, and the output is the same as is stored in the DB. But still I cannot log in. The log in prompt just reloads, no error message or anything. Any ideas?

I've also tried clearing cache/sessions/etc, and even a different browser to no affect.

Crossposted from the PyroCMS forum: https://www.pyrocms.com/forums/topics/view/19323

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, since there doesn't seem to be any good suggestions found either here or on the PyroCMS forums and my site is very small content wise I decided to just wipe everything and do a clean install of the latest build instead.

Not a very good solution for future reference, but it will have to do.

Answer (score 0):

From my checklist (it's been a while since I had this happen to me):

- If you didn't get an incorrect password error, it may well be you were just being redirected back to the login page before the details were even checked. You can run into issues with enabling the 'Remove index.php from URL' in .htaccess - in `/system/cms/config/config.php` try changing
  `$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';`
  to `$config['index_page'] = '';`

or (as you've hinted):

- clear the contents of default_ci_sessions table
- clear the cookies for the domain (a quicker way is to just open a new Google Incognito window which won't have any cookies).

Also - you can initiate a password reset for the admin password using the ordinary user login form if you or someone else *does* ever forget it (don't though).